# Comment System showing different type of IP

Tags: comments

I am observing different type of IP in comment.

IP is like this 2409:4064:695:f112:bb92:1b9a:de27:d3fb

[image]

Website is [nvshq.org](https://nvshq.org/)

Is this any type of spam or security concern?

Answer (score 1):

This look like a valid [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) that uses 128 bit addresses, instead of the older 32 bit addresses of [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address) that have already been [exhausted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion).

Here's a schema picture of an IPv6 address from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#/media/File:Ipv6_address_leading_zeros.svg):

[image: IPv6]

Even though the IP address is valid, it's another matter if the comment is a spam or not. I assume the the question is only regarding the format of the IP address.